# Treasure boxes in FF XIII-2

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Is it possible to permanently lose the contents of a treasure box or can you somehow return and redo something to respawn the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treasure boxes have, and probably always will be, one time occurrences in the Final Fantasy series. Therefore, if you sell a unique item you will permanently no longer have access to the item (I found out the hard way with the bloody `Morph` materia in FF7). There are no missable items in FF13-2 so unless you sell it, you can get it.

The only exceptions to these are mini-games. Although I don't think any mini-game in FF13-2 gives a treasure box as a reward.

Another point to note is the `Live Trigger` rewards. You get rewards, kind of like the treasure box, for a 'funny' answer and a 'serious' answer. You can use `Time Reversal` to replay these events and retrieve the missed items. But once you have both items, they cannot be gotten again.

Comment: Your last paragraph adresses exactly what I was asking. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you sell the contents ;) otherwise you'll be able to obtain them in any time line, unless it's already opened, be it in the future or past.
There is also no way to respawn the treasure balls, time reversal doesn't work either (the same thing goes for treasure cubes).

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: So if I opened a treasure box and I got a potion there is no way to respawn the box to get the nicer reward?

Comment: @Chu What do you mean by `nicer reward`?

Comment: @user1016253: The other rewards you get when you do funny answers to the Live Trigger sequences.

Comment: @Chu Ahhh, blind luck I added that in as an extra ha.